# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'score'

Tags: python, numpy, attributeerror, conv-neural-network, sequential

i was working with convolutional neural nertworks , while using sequential i got problemsto train data. using  sequential is it not possible to get best score??

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import reshape
import numpy as np
def model_CNN(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=32, padding='same', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 1)))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=32, padding='same', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2)) # This is the dropout layer. It's main function is to inactivate 20% of neurons in order to prevent overfitting
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=32, padding='same', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=32, padding='same', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))

    model.add(Flatten())

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.5)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    convolutional_model = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5,batch_size=64,verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
    print(convolutional_model.score(X_train,Y_train))
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Traceback recived as error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-9a2005301144> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 convolutional_model= model_CNN(X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test)
      3 print(convolutional_model)

<ipython-input-49-bac0ec08f100> in model_CNN(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
     34     model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
     35     convolutional_model = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5,batch_size=64,verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
---> 36     print(convolutional_model.score(X_train,Y_train))
     37     # Print the summary of the model
     38     model.summary()

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'score'
```

since im new to python,i got troubled and checked various resourses,but nothing helped,please guide me...
i got the error from this line

```
print(convolutional_model.score(X_train,Y_train))
```

if it's not possible please guide me for a better one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `model` not `convolutional_model` object. `fit` function returns an history object which contains some information about training phase like loss, accuracy.. it depends on your loss function and metric functions.

Can you try this?

`print(model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train))`

Comment: I fixed the code block can you check it? @ShibinRobin

Comment: The problem may be using parenthesis. Try this one `model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train)`

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how to get this `no attribute` error. I think you should double-check your implementation and run it again.

Comment: I am a hundred percent sure, you need to use this code block `score = model.evaluate(X_train, Y_train);
print("Test loss:", score[0]);
print("Test accuracy:", score[1])` and you have some other problems. I can help if you send the whole code implementation

Comment: i've checked it.... and it's working fine... Thank you .... data value changed by  optimizer which resulted your code into trouble...thank you for the effort @Cenk Bircanoglu